# One more Css3Pie not working with border-radius

Tags: css, rounded-corners, css3pie

i read a ton of similar problems and test all solutions but no one works...

this is my css:

```
.button
{   
    background-image:url(../Immagini/pulsante.jpg) !important;
    background-color:#004878;
    padding:0.4em 1em;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border:1px solid #C5DBEC;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:0.1em;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    behavior: url(../Scripts/css3Pie/PIE.php);
}
```

i add a simply alert in the file (even in the htc ones) and it's shown so the file is loaded.

as you can see i use the php version to avoid server problem but nothing change

i try even to remove `!important` in css but still it didn't work

What i miss?

**EDIT**

this is my folder structure:

```
ROOT
-->Defalut.aspx
-->Pages
     -->Page.aspx
-->Scripts
   -->cs3Pie
      -->PIE.php
      -->all other css3Pie...
-->Css
   -->Style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

From [css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/) about behavior:

*Note: this path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.*

Just you absolute path

```
-ms-behavior: url("http://css3pie.com/pie/PIE.htc");
```

or path relative to html:

```
/* You need to use this code if your html file in <site>/index.php
   And PIE-file in <site>/Scripts/css3Pie/PIE.php
   
   Also check if your get access to PIE-file from your browser
   via link like http://<site>/Scripts/css3Pie/PIE.php
*/
-ms-behavior: url("/Scripts/css3Pie/PIE.php);
```

### [> Working example on CodePen (tested in ie8)](http://codepen.io/probil/pen/bFsdf)

Comment: i have a reverse proxy, can't use absolute path since it change. the path i write is relative to the web page, since all my pages are in a folder under root

Comment: Would you like to write folder structure of your index.php, style file and PIE.php? If it such like this:
<site>/index.php[main page] <site>/Scripts/css3Pie/PIE.php[PIE]
You need to use "behavior: url(/Scripts/css3Pie/PIE.php);"

Comment: question edited with folder structure. site is in .net not php

Comment: Php version forks only on servers with php support. Standart Asp.net configuration of IIS does not support php out of box. Why you don't use *.htc version? It's work great on any modern server. Try to read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987447/css3pie-or-pie-htc-in-asp-net). Some guys recomend to use [this trick](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=97) for relative linking to asp.net.